# Filtering output by a list with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi

What I am trying to do is take logon names that are older than 90 days and compare them to the list of current profiles in output from `Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile`. I have tried for what seems like hours and am still unable to figure out why it doesn't process the list of names as (I think) it should.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName wsci201oit -ScriptBlock {
    $AllUsers = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object -FilterScript {
        $_.LocalPath -notlike 'c:\windows*' -and
        $_.LocalPath -notlike '*ADMINISTRATOR' -and
        $_.LocalPath -notlike '*Public' -and
        $_.LocalPath -notlike '*Temp'
    } | Select-Object -Property LocalPath, SID

    $Over90 = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | where {
        $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -and
        $_.Name -notlike 'ADMINISTRATOR' -and
        $_.Name -notlike 'Public' -and
        $_.Name -notlike 'TEMP'
    } | Select-Object Name
    $Over90 | Select-Object Name | Out-File C:\Windows\Temp\Over90.txt
    $List = Get-Content -Path C:\Windows\Temp\Over90.txt

    $AllUsers | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath -like "*$List" }
}
```

The outlput of `$AllUsers` contains a path like C:\Users\adm-thomas and the SID. The output of `$List` contains just adm-thomas. I am trying to match the "adm-thomas" from `$List` to the "C:\Users\adm-thomas" LocalPath and test against each name in `$List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you may want to adjust is the handling of the subfolders of `C:\Users`. Writing the list of the subfolder names to a file, then reading that file in the next instruction, is completely pointless. Worse, since you don't remove the table header you could get a false positive if you happen to have a user account "name". Simply expand the `Name` property to get a list of the folder names. You can also simplify the filtering by checking the name against a list of names to exclude.

```
$excludes  = 'ADMINISTRATOR', 'Public', 'TEMP'
$threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
...
$List = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt $threshold -and
    $exclude -notcontains $_.Name
} | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Then you'll want to adjust the data you retrieve from the `Win32_UserProfile` class. Since only the leaf portion of the path is relevant for the later comparison use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for extracting just that information:

```
... | Select-Object @{n='Username';e={Split-Path -Leaf $_.LocalPath}}, SID | ...
```

That way you can filter the result against `$List` from above:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {
    $_.LocalPath -notlike 'c:\windows*'
} | Select-Object @{n='Username';e={Split-Path -Leaf $_.LocalPath}}, SID | Where-Object {
    $List -contains $_.Username
}
```

Comment: I was unaware of the split-path command as that completely eliminated the issue I was having. I only wrote the results to a list partly out of frustration and partly because all of this is contained within an `invoke-command` and it would pull PSComputerName and RunspaceId regardless of my `select-object`. This is much more elegant than my original attempt but I can still understand it so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `FullPath` property from `Get-ChildItem`, but it seems more efficient to just get the same information from the `LastUseTime` property of `Win32_UserProfile` and then the whole command can just be a filtered remote WMI lookup.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName wsci201oit |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Special -eq $False -and
        $_.SID -notmatch '-500$' -and
        $_.LastUseTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) 
    } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty LocalPath, SID
```

Notes: I used the CIM cmdlets which operate over WSMAN by default. There is a `Special` property that gets rid of all of the special users except local administrator. Then matching off of the SID is safer in case Administrator has been renamed.

Comment: I tried this initially but nearly half of my profiles didn't have a `LastUseTime`. That's pretty awesome about the `Special` property though.